# Custom Poll Web Part

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-online

I am creating a custom poll webpart using the following two lists:

1) QuestionList : Stores questions of poll (QuestionId,QuestionDate,Votes,TakenBy)

2) OptionsList: Stores option pertaining to a particular question (OptionId, Question(LookUp), Votes)

I have implemented the functionality. But my concern here is when multiple users try to submit their votes I am not able to achieve concurrency.

I using **Sharepoint Web Services** to achieve the functionality.

Can some one please throw some light on the issue?

Comment: why not using sharepoint surveys ?

Comment: Because in sharepoint surveys, questions are stored as columns and not rows. I want to dynamically show the questions based on the date on which they are added / the date for which the poll is scheduled

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the Vote column and add a UserVotes List with the columns User, Option (Lookup). For each vote you add a entry in the UserVotes List with the user and the Option for which the user voted. To Display the number of votes you can get how many items exists in the UserVotes list with this option.